# rake snorby:setup error - "cannot load such file — dm-rails/railtie"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having some trouble getting Snorby running for the first time. I installed Snorby and all prerequisites according to the instructions at snorby.org, but when I run the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake snorby:setup
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- dm-rails/railtie
```

I ran `gem list --local` to verify that dm-rails is installed on my system.
Version issue maybe??
Not quite sure how to troubleshoot...

My system details: a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See here for the details of the fix: https://github.com/Snorby/snorby/issues/355

Long story short it appears that bundler needs to be installed with a specific version to work with the other gems required by Snorby (2.6.2) as defined in the Gemfile.

Install dm-rails and bundler in v1.2.1 and it should work.